# Using Groovy to Loop and Execute Test Steps

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm trying to do dynamic testing where I query the database, use Groovy to loop through and gather the data I need, and execute the validation web service with the results from the database call.

Here is my code:

```
response = context.expand('${JDBC Get User Task#ResponseAsXml}')

String userTaskId
int r = 1

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
tc = testRunner.testCase
ts = tc.testSteps["Get usertask by id"]

root.ResultSet.Row.each{ row ->
    log.info "Data for row: " + r.toString()

    userTaskId = row["USER_TASKS.USER_TASK_ID"]
    tc.setPropertyValue("result", userTaskId)

    ts.run(testRunner, context)

    r++
}
```

The problem I'm having is that if 3 results are returned, the only one that gets executed is the 3rd time into the validation web service.

Comment: Can you check with `testRunner.runTestStepByName('Get usertask by id')` instead of `ts.run(testRunner, context)` and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: @user3259301  maybe an issue with iterartor. try to use `root.children().each` . Show your xml structure, so people have better idea.